Why decrypting Custom DES with block of 16 Bytes giving me unreadable text in python
I have this task to build customizable Des Encryption where each block is 16 Bytes instead of 8 Bytes, we don't want to using triple Des( thats not the purpose )
here are the
The block ( P ) is of size 128 bits (16 bytes).
It is divided into two blocks of 8 bytes P_1   P_2
Each key is of size 192 bits (24 bytes) divided into 3 sub-keys of 8 bytes each K_1, K_2,K_3
The encryption process is done as described in the diagram after this description, basically a feistel diagram with just 3 roundes , where each round the F function is basic Des from the library pyDes  .
The encryption result of DES of each block is  C
The encryption is DES with the key that changes from block to block C = C_1C_2 .
I need to write the power_des.py module that will display the algorithm described above. The module should be based on the des algorithm in the pyDes library.
we need to use the padding according to the PKCS5
Use only the CBC mode
I need be able to decrypt the encrypted file  to retrieve back the   plain text
**Problem description: **
Im able to encrypt and decrypt the file,
Im not able to read the decrypted file ( i can open the file, but the text inside the file looks in weird ascii )
i think  the problem is one of those
1 The way i save the format of the  decrypted data
2 missed something in the decryption process,
3: the unpading just before returning the plain  text  is not done properly
3: or something else
I will be glad to know what i need to fix  to retrieve my data back and readable
In  Short:
For encryption
I pad the text so it could be in blocks of 16 Bytes
i loop text in block of 16 , for each  block i encrypt the block  using the function __ek(block) using  feistel 3 round and des function with different key for each round
I  save blocks  of 16 byts with CBC mode
I save the encrypted file with the iv in the first 16 Bytes
iv +  text
For decryption
I retrieve the file , extract the iv and for each 16 block i decrypt with  mode CBC and the the ___Dk(block) function
CODE
from os import urandom
import  os
from  pyDes import des
import  hashlib
import sys
import numpy as np


class PowerDes:
   def __init__(self, password, mode,):
       # passwd.encode('utf-8').digest(), convert the str pass to 32 bytes
       # [:24] we want the first  24 bytes of the 32 bytes
       key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:24]

       if mode != 'CBC':
           raise ValueError('Illegal mode')
       self.__blocksize = 16
       self.key1 = key[:8]
       self.key2 = key[8:16]
       self.key3 = key[16:]

   def __xor8(self, x, y):
       a = np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.int8)
       b = np.frombuffer(y, dtype=np.int8)
       z= np.bitwise_xor(a, b).tobytes()
       return z

   def __xor16(self, x, y):
       a = np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.int16)
       b = np.frombuffer(y, dtype=np.int16)
       z= np.bitwise_xor(a, b).tobytes()
       return z

   # this is the power Des of 1 block of 16 Bytes
   def __ek(self, block):
       # Split the block into two 8-byte halves
       pleft = block[:8]
       pright = block[8:]

       # Three keys for three rounds
       keys = [self.key1, self.key2, self.key3]

       for i in range(3):

           des_cipher = des(keys[i]) # des object with i key
           # Encrypt the right half
           pi = des_cipher.encrypt(pright)
           # XOR with the left half
           pie2Xored = self.__xor8(pleft, pi)
           # Swap halves
           pleft = pright
           pright = pie2Xored

       # After final round, swap halves back
       return pright + pleft

   # this is the power Des of 1 block of 16 Bytes
   def __dk(self, block):
       # Split the block into two 8-byte halves
       pleft = block[:8]
       pright = block[8:]

       # Three keys for three rounds in reverse order
       keys = [self.key3, self.key2, self.key1]

       for i in range(3):
           des_cipher = des(keys[i])
           pi = des_cipher.encrypt(pright)
           pie2 = self.__xor8(pleft, pi)
           pleft = pright
           pright =  pie2

       # After final round, swap halves back (back to the orginal shape)
       return pleft + pright


   def __pad(self, ptext):
       # pad using mode # PKCS5
       pad_len = 16 - (len(ptext) % 16)
       padding = bytes([pad_len] * pad_len)
       paddedText =  ptext + padding
       return paddedText

   def __unpad(self, ptext):
       pad_len = ptext[-1]
       return ptext[:-pad_len]


   def encrypt(self, ptext ):
       '''

       :param ptext: the text to be encrypted
       :return: encrypted text

           encrypt each 16 block with Mood CBC
           loop the text - on each 16B chunck call ek(Block)
       '''
       ptext = self.__pad(ptext)
       # loop the text encrypt Using Des of 16
       iv = urandom(16)
       c = []
       c_i_minus1 = iv
       blocks = [ptext[i:i + 16] for i in range(0, len(ptext), 16)]
       for pi in blocks:
           '''
               C_i = e_k(pi XOR C_i-1 )
           '''
           c_block = self.__xor16(c_i_minus1, pi)  # pi XOR C_i-1
           ci = self.__ek(c_block)
           c.append(ci)
           c_i_minus1 = ci

       ## append the iv to the text
       ciphertext = iv + b"".join(c)

       return ciphertext

   def decrypt(self, ctext):
       decrypted = []

       blocks = [ctext[i:i + 16] for i in range(0, len(ctext), 16)]
       iv = blocks[0] # extrac the iv
       cBLoks = blocks[1:]

       for i in range(0, len(cBLoks)):
           if i == 0 :
               p = self.__dk(cBLoks[0])
               p1 = self.__xor16(p, iv)
               decrypted.append(p1)
           else:
               c = cBLoks[i]
               prev_c = cBLoks[i - 1]
               p = self.__dk(c)
               p_i = self.__xor16(p, prev_c)
               decrypted.append(p_i)


       decrypted_data = b"".join(decrypted)
       decrypted_data = self.__unpad(decrypted_data)
       # unpading should go  here
       return decrypted_data

def saveFiletoSystem(text, file_name, post):
   print("Saving the file ")
   # extract file name
   base = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
   new_file_name = f"{base}.{post}"
   with open(new_file_name, 'wb') as f:
       f.write(text)
   print("saved file toSystem .")



def runer():
   command = input("Enter Command e or d: ")
   file_name = input("enter file name {make sure its in the same dir}: ")
   seed = input("Enter password: ")

   # open the file !

   if command == 'e':
       with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
           ptext = f.read()

       power_des = PowerDes(seed, mode='CBC') # Create the Encryption Object
       cipher = power_des.encrypt(ptext) #recive the encrypted file
       saveFiletoSystem(cipher , file_name  , 'pds')
       print("Crated Encrypted file  .. .")
   # Decryption
   elif command == 'd':
       with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
           ctext = f.read()

       power_des = PowerDes(seed, mode='CBC')  # Create the Encryption Object
       plain = power_des.encrypt(ctext)  # recive the encrypted file
       saveFiletoSystem(plain, file_name, 'dec')
       print("Crated Decrypted  file  .. .")
   else:
       print("Wrong input")
       sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   runer()







I'm not 100% sure, but I think in __dk, the return line should be return pright + pleft to actually swap the parts back

Also, I really hope this code is not used to "protect" any sensitive data. The only good use of it would be as an exercise for cryptanalysis

During decryption, i.e. in the d branch of runer(), encrypt() is called instead of decrypt().

@Topaco yes  thats right, thank you  i changed it , now my. decrypted file is empty ,  i thinkits somethig with the padding , so  i removed the padding and the unpadding functions and sent a 16 Bytes  of text  for now , and when i decrypt i also geting weired text  in some ascii represnation  for example encryptin the text abcdabcdabcdabcd after decryption i get so mething like this �SHO���SHO����

@Aemyl yes is for practicing only i did change __dk to return pright + pleft ,now i get the correct text. it fixed the. issue , but for now that just work with out the padding with text if  16 Bytes blocks multiplications Thankk you

there where no proplem wiith the unpading,oonce i fixed  return pright + pleft and the runner in the d branch calling the decrypt() function,  all the code now works  fine thank you

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Ok will thank you

i was able to fix the  issues, and here what i did
During decryption, i.e. in the d branch of runer() ,   decrypt() is now called instead of encrypt().
in __dk, the return line should be return pright + pleft to actually swap the parts back insted of   pleft + pright 
